# Match substring with regex for one or more capitalised words between quotation marks

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have the following string:

```
example_string <- "In this document, Defined Terms are quotation marks, followed by definition. \"Third Party Software\" is software owned by third parties. \"USA\" the United States of America. \"Breach of Contract\" is in accordance with the Services Description."
```

I want to extract every substring which is at least partially capitalised and is sandwiched by quotation marks. So the output should be:

```
"Third Party Software"  "USA"  "Breach of Contract"
```

I got as far as this with the regex:

```
str_extract_all(example_string, "(?:\")\\w(\\s*\\w+)*")

[[1]]
[1] "\"Third Party Software" "\"USA"                  "\"Breach of Contract"
```

I can't figure out a way to avoid matching the opening escaped quotation mark `\"`. I know I can just add a `gsub` line to clean it out after extracting the defined terms, but I think there must be a way to do it all in one regex call.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: So the first letter after opening `"` must be a capital letter? What do you mean by "at least partially capitalised"?

Comment: First letter is always capitalised. I said "at least partially" because there are instances like "Breach of Contract" where one word isn't capitalised, and instances like "USA" where the whole word is capitalised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your expression, `(?:")\w(\s*\w+)*"`, you match and *consume* the `"` char using a non-capturing `(?:")` group. Thus, it lands in the match value.

You might have wanted to use

```
"(?<=\")\\w(\\s*\\w+)*"
```

where `(?<=")` is a positive lookbehind that matches a *location* that is immediately preceded with a `"` char.

**However**, when you have identical single char right and left delimiters, I'd rather use a *capturing* approach.

You can use `stringr::str_match_all` with

```
"(\p{Lu}[^"]*)"
```

Or, it can also be your pattern, a bit modified:

```
"(\p{Lu}\w*(?:\s+\w+)*)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qBn779/1), or [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/qBn779/2). Details:

- `"` - a `"` char
- `(\p{Lu}[^"]*)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `\p{Lu}` - any Unicode uppercase letter
  - `[^"]*` - any zero or more chars other than `"`
- `\w*(?:\s+\w+)*` - 0+ letters, digits, underscores, and then 0+ occurrences of 1+ whitespaces followed with 1+ letters, digits, underscores
- `"` - a `"` char.

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/ZI5E9s):

```
library(stringr)
example_string <- "In this document, Defined Terms are quotation marks, followed by definition. \"Third Party Software\" is software owned by third parties. \"USA\" the United States of America. \"Breach of Contract\" is in accordance with the Services Description."
res <- str_match_all(example_string, '"(\\p{Lu}[^"]*)"')
unlist(lapply(res, function(x) x[,-1]))
## => [1] "Third Party Software" "USA"                  "Breach of Contract"
```

Comment: Thank you! I could achieve the same thing with my regex and `gsub("\"", "", res[ , 2])`, my question was more about why it's not possible to capture WITHIN the opening quotation mark without including that quotation mark.

Comment: @mendy You consumed it. You need `"(?<=\")\\w(\\s*\\w+)*(?=\")"` perhaps, then. I added some more details to the answer.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question. Why is your preference for a capturing approach when the delimiters are identical?

Comment: @mendy Comapre [this](https://regex101.com/r/eNxBNB/1) to [this](https://regex101.com/r/eNxBNB/2).

Comment: Ah I see, it avoids reading the characters on either side of the quoted chunks as being themselves within the quotation marks?

Comment: @mendy It makes it impossible for the regex engine to try matching from the trailing delimiter since both are consumed.